# Insert and Check for Copies of Data using SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parsing

So I'm upgrading an old parser right now. It's written in C# and uses SQL to insert records into a database.

Currently it reads and parses a few thousand lines of data from a file, then inserts the new data into a database containing over a million records.

Sometimes it can take over 10 minutes just to add a few thousand lines.

I've come to the conclusion that this bottleneck in performance is due to a SQL command where it uses an `IF NOT EXISTS` statement to determine whether the row attempting to be inserted already exists, and if it doesn't insert the record.

I believe the problem is that it just takes way too long to call the `IF NOT EXISTS` on every single row in the new data.

Is there a faster way to determine whether data exists already or not?

I was thinking to insert all of the records first anyways using the `SQLBulkCopy` Class, then running a stored procedure to remove the duplicates.

Does anyone else have any suggestions or methods to do this as efficiently and quickly as possible? Anything would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I'd run a stored procedure (on the large table) after copying the new data into the large table

large table = 1,000,000+ rows

Comment: Are stored procedures on or off the table as a possible inclusion?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very good with SQL (really databases in general). If what your asking is if I can use stored procedures, then yes I can.

Comment: How are you determining if a row 'already exists', comparing all fields or just a key of some sort?

Comment: The table has ~20 columns, and checks if 4 of the columns have the same values (LocationID, LocationDate, FName, LName)

Comment: I know this is 2 years old... but a proc with a table valued parameter and a merge statement could do this very nicely without the not exists. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
1.  Create an IDataReader to loop over your source data.
2.  Place the values into a strong dataset.
3.  Every N number of rows, send the dataset (.GetXml) to a stored procedure.  Let's say 1000 for the heck of it.
4.  Have the stored procedure shred the xml.
5.  Do your INSERT/UPDATE based on this shredded xml.
6.  Return from the procedure, keep looping until you're done.
```

Here is an older example:
http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

The key is that you are doing "bulk" operations.......instead of row by row.  And you can pick a sweet spot # (1000 for example) that gives you the best performance.

Comment: I think this is an interesting approach. Although, what is the advantage of using this method, rather than getting the XML, shredding all of it at once then running a stored procedure on the table then? Or just inserting all the data into the table using the SQBulkCopy, then running the procedure.

Comment: Xml performance will "struggle" if the xml document is too big.  But if you think you can pull it off with one hit, then go for it.  The "if exists" check can be done against the @variable table....thus one hit for the inserts (that do not already exist).  Index rebuilding is delayed until all rows are inserted (bonus!)....

Comment: My example shows you can run a few business rules on the import-data before inserting.........that would be one advantage.  I'm not saying it is "the answer", but it is a good approach if you ever want to pre-massage the data.......keep the sql simple crud...not a bunch of if/else/case/this/that stuff.